# Kubernetes NodePort doesn't return the response from the container

Tags: docker, flask, kubernetes

I've developed a containerized Flask application and I want to deploy it with Kubernetes. However, I can't connect the ports of the Container with the Service correctly.

Here is my Deployment file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: <my-app-name>
spec:
  replicas: 1

  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: flaskapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: <container-name>
        image: <container-image>
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:  
        - containerPort: 5000
          name: http-port
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: <service-name>
spec:
  selector:
    app: flaskapp
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5000
    port: 5000
    nodePort: 30013
  type: NodePort
```

When I run `kubectl get pods`, everything seems to work fine:

```
NAME                              READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
<pod-id>                          1/1       Running   0          7m
```

When I run `kubectl get services`, I get the following:

```
NAME                  TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         
<service-name>        NodePort    10.105.247.63   <none>      5000:30013/TCP
...
```

However, when I give the following URL to the browser: 10.105.247.63:30013, the browser keeps loading but never returns the data from the application.

Does anyone know where the problem could be? It seems that the service is not connected to the container's port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`30013` is the port on the Node not in the cluster IP. To get a reply you would have to connect to `<IP-address-of-the-node>:30013`. To get the list of nodes you can:

```
kubectl get nodes -o=wide
```

You can also go through the `CLUSTER-IP` but you'll have to use the exposed port `5000`: `10.105.247.63:5000`

Comment: Hello Rico! Thank you for your answer! After getting the list of nodes(only have one, since I'm using Minikube), the IP of the node is not shown! Do you know how could I find it? Thank you once again!

Comment: It's the IP of you minikube VM.